# magento 1.9 Show products ONLY to logged in customer

Tags: magento-1.9

I need a way that products should be visible for only logged in customers
Someone said me that I should use catalog_product_collection_load_before Event
How can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this functionality you can use some free extension ( you will find some on google ) or you can implement a check on your catalog listing page :

Extension :

https://github.com/jreinke/magento-require-login

if you want to apply custom code you can apply below code in following file ( top ):

```
1) app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml

2) app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml
```

Code :

```
<?php
 if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'));
}
?>
```